# How to add QMYSQL driver on qt to link my project with phpmyadmin?

Tags: qt

I need to install QMYSQL plugin when I run my code i get this: QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC.

Comment: What platform are you on? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Platform == Linux, Windows, MacOS X, other?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile MySql plugin yourself. For this you need MySql library to link with. However, since you aleady have QODBC plugin, you can use [ODBC MySql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). This way you do not need to compile anything, just install the connector and configure correctly the ODBC source.